# Inserting nested data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am making a simple backend for my shopping cart application and the data is nested.

This are some of the fields of the collection

```
db.now.insert( { name: "admin", status: "online"})
```

and this here is the nested data

```
    "catalog" : [
            {
                "objectid" : 1,
                "message" : "sold",
                "status" : "open"
            },
            {
                "objectid" : 12,
                "message" : "not sold",
                "status" : "open"
            }


]
```

I wrote the two snippets to be separately but i would like to know how i `catalog` can be part of the insert statement. I would also like to know if the `objectid` field in the catalog can be unique.

Thanks.

Comment: The catalog is just an example of the nested data i want to insert to my collection alongside this fields `db.now.insert( { name: "admin", status: "online"})` . The problem i am facing is,i dont know how to include the nested data in an insert statement.

Comment: Just put it right in the same object: `{ name: "admin", status: "online", catalog: [...]}`

Comment: Okay thanks. What about objectid,can i create a unique one for every nested item i add?

Comment: I would suggest you to let Mongo handle the `_id` field part automatically... unless you need to do something really fancy which doesn't seem to be your case.

Comment: I have this `{
            "objectid" : ObjectId(),
            "message" : "sold",
            "status" : "open"
        },`  which gives `{
   "objectid" : ObjectId("570024014a7f7f1343d4718f"),
   "message" : "sold",
   "status" : "open"
  },` How can i strip ObjectId to be left with the real objectid string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete snippet thanks to the help of @JohnnyHk and others

```
db.now.insert( { name: "admin", status: "online",catalog : [
        {
            "objectid" : ObjectId().str,
            "message" : "sold",
            "status" : "open"
        },
        {
             "objectid" : ObjectId().str,
            "message" : "not sold",
            "status" : "open"
        }
    ]})
```

That produced

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("570024f14a7f7f1343d47194"),
    "name" : "admin",
    "status" : "online",
    "catalog" : [
        {
            "objectid" : "570024f14a7f7f1343d47192",
            "message" : "sold",
            "status" : "open"
        },
        {
            "objectid" : "570024f14a7f7f1343d47193",
            "message" : "not sold",
            "status" : "open"
        }
    ]
}
```